# Как использовать PARALLEL для выполнения запроса?

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация, plsql

Как можно оптимизировать запрос, если например, в таблице огромное количество записей?

Не пойму, как применить `PARALLEL`? Что она делает?

Comment: Возможно вам помогли бы быстрее, если вы опишите запрос и таблицы на которых он строится. Скорее всего проблему можно решить, индексированием, партиционированием и распараллеливанием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно вы имеете ввиду подсказку [PARALLEL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-D25225CE-2DCE-4D9F-8E82-401839690A6E):

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(таблица, целое число потоков) */ <запрос>
```

Данная подсказка указывает оптимизатору использовать несколько процессов для одновременной работы. Имхо, имеет смысл использовать при большой партиционированной таблице фактов, с множеством справочников.

Начиная с версии 11.2, вы можете указать вместо таблицы, представление или даже целый подзапрос.

Answer (score 2):

С подсказкой `PARALLEL` SQL интерпретатор полностью управляет процессом  распараллеливания и выполняет его на уровне запроса (*statement-level*). To есть, при возникновении ошибки в общем случае, весь запрос завершится ошибкой и откатом всех изменений.

В некоторых случаях, будет целесообразно перенять управленние распараллеливанием (*application-level*), тогда будет возможно, например, при возникновении ошибки в отдельной цепочке повторить ее выполнение.

Для этого есть пакет [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.html#GUID-D13B6975-09B5-4711-AD43-45F68228C1CC). На минимальном примере можно составить представление, как это работает и какие возможности это даст.

Тестовые данные:

```
create table tab (id number primary key, memo varchar2 (96), flag number, sesid number);

insert /*+ append */ into tab
    select 
        level, 'memo for '||level, 
        case when mod (level,5) = 0 THEN 10 when mod (level,3) = 0 then 20 else 30 end, 
        null
from dual connect by level <= 1e5;

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats (user, 'tab', cascade=>true);

      FLAG      COUNT
---------- ----------
        10      20000
        20      26667
        30      53333
```

Так создаётся задание и определяются цепочки выполнения:

```
begin 
    dbms_parallel_execute.create_task (task_name => 'pe');

    dbms_parallel_execute.create_chunks_by_rowid (
        task_name=>'pe', table_owner=>user, table_name  => 'TAB', by_row=>true, chunk_size=>10000);
end;
/
```

Пример заапуска для обновления таблицы:

```
declare
    stmt varchar2 (32767);
begin
    stmt := q'[
        update tab t 
            set flag = flag + 10,
            sesid = sys_context ('userenv','sessionid')
        where rowid between :start_id and :end_id]';
    dbms_parallel_execute.run_task (
        task_name=>'pe', sql_stmt=>stmt, language_flag=>dbms_sql.native, parallel_level=>10
    );
end;
/
```

В результате, обновление было выполнено параллельно в десяти сессиях:

```
select sesid, count (1) cntses 
from tab
group by sesid;

     SESID     CNTSES
---------- ----------
    758636      12384
    758630      12126
    [...]
    758640      12900

10 rows selected.
```